# how to show date before 1967 for Date of Birth in bootstrap daterangepicker

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12"><b>DOB</b> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
        <div> 
            <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('self_dob', array(
                'label' => false,
                'placeholder'=>'dd/mm/yyyy',
                'type' => 'text',
                'id' => "self_dob",
                'class' => 'form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12')
            );
            ?>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is daterangpicker

```js
$.fn.customDatePicker3 = function() {
    $(this).on("apply.daterangepicker", function(e, picker) {
        picker.element.val(picker.startDate.format(picker.locale.format));
    });

    return $(this).daterangepicker({
        locale: {
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        },
        singleDatePicker: true,
        showDropdowns: true,
        autoUpdateInput: false,
        singleClasses: "picker_1",
    });
};

$("#self_dob").customDatePicker3();
```

This is my daterange picker which is only showing dates to select only from 1967.  How to show dates before 1967 or earlier dates. Please help. I am using cakephp 3.x.

Comment: You can set startDate option at the time of initialization. Ref : http://www.daterangepicker.com/#options

You can also check this by setting config here : http://www.daterangepicker.com/#config

Comment: No its not working properly i have tried it already.

Comment: May you create a jsfiddle of the code?

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui You shouldn't recommend JSFiddle, SO has it's own fiddle magic.